# How to check if item is selected or not in pyqt listwidget

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a form built in pyqt5 there are 3 fields 
line edit
combobox
listwidget
I want to validate all three fields
I can validate line edit if is empty or not
I can validate if item select from combobox or not
but I am unable to validate if listwidget item selected or not

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I did not understand

Comment: Please read the link, it seems that you have a custom qlistwidget so to check if an item is selected will depend on how you have implemented it.

Comment: Ok I understand I will post my code latter.